# Username in the Votes Cast section of the profile page of mobile web

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, mobile-web, votes-tab

If you open your profile page in the mobile web version of site, you can see your name in the Votes Cast section. For example in the [my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/339911/alexolut):

[image: votes cast]

Why username exists in this section? Is it really needed here? I already know who's the owner of the profile.